# How to convert the date time to date in Sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

I have a column (transaction dates) in a table (records). The current format for the date is (YYYY MM DD HH MM SS) or something really close to it. I want to convert it to YY MM DD. How can I do this for the entire column?

I've tried alter commands.  I've tried one variant of this:

```
SELECT strftime('%d-%m-%Y', 'now')
```

But only got errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite doesn't have a built-in date type so some applications use strings or a number to store the date. If your application is one of those using strings then you have a couple choices.

1. Recommended: You could convert the string at the time you perform the query by using one of the SQLite date functions (similar to the SQL you provided).
2. You can update (using SQL - UPDATE) all of the stored date strings to a new string format. ALTER TABLE cannot be used to change the column definition for this purpose since SQLite doesn't support DATE as a column type. Be aware that SQLite has a list of string formats (and one numeric format) that it supports if you plan to use the SQLite date functions.

I don't know your specific situation but since this is what you asked: If you want to change the string representation in the existing column (presuming it is a string in the format you described) you can try something like the following:

```
UPDATE records SET [transaction dates]=strftime('%Y-%m-%d', [transaction dates]);
```

BTW: There was nothing wrong with your query so perhaps you could send the error you were getting. The following query worked perfectly fine for me.

```
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d', 'now');
returned:
2019-07-13
```

See the following for more information on dates in SQLite.
https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: So when I try to retrieve the data, using the 

select transaction dates from  records;

I can not input now there right? I will have to input the column name?

Comment: Correct, when retrieving the date from the table into a specific format you should provide the column name instead of 'now'. something like: SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d', [transaction dates]) FROM records … etc.